# slideToggle not expanding element

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I'm using slideToggle() to expand elements in a panel. Upon clicking, the function does not expand said elements.

Here's the code:

**HTML**

```
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h6 class="panel-title" style="text-align: center;"><a href='#' class="accordion-toggle">Risks</a></h6>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-content" id="risks" style="height: 0;overflow: hidden;">
      <div class="panel-body" style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px;">5.8%</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){

  //Expand or collapse this panel
  $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');

  //Hide the other panels
  $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did is, going two layers up and then look for the requested element in the siblings of the parent-parent-element.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".accordion-toggle").click(function(){
      $(".accordion-toggle").not(this).parent().parent().siblings(".accordion-content").slideUp();
      $(this).parent().parent().siblings(".accordion-content").slideToggle("fast");
   });
  });
```

I made a fiddle for you here: https://jsfiddle.net/aLedkzw6/1/

Made an edit. Here you go.

Comment: Everything's working as intended! I suspected something along those lines were the cause, but was having some trouble conceptualizing the code. Thanks for the help.